# take values in the table this month and the previous month

Tags: php, mysql

well, I'm using the DATEDIFF command, but am having problems.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usu4r10s WHERE premium IS NULL AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `data`) < 30";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usu4r10s WHERE premium IS NULL AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `data`) > 0";
```

from what I understand, he picks the date and deducts 30 days right?
but has a problem in that code and do not know how the timestamp

we are in March right? want to get the values ​​of February and March in a more practical way.
maybe the question is kind of silly, but I tried too much about it before posting my question.

Answer (score 0):

For past two months you would use something like..

```
SELECT ... FROM usu4r10s WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

Which would fetch records that have a `date` greater than `January, 28 2013 18:02:24+0000` (as of now).

Comment: I understand, but what the current month?

Comment: @BrunoRibeiro This will include January 28 ... 31, Feb 1 .. 28, March 1 .. 28